# How to unit test code blocks in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito, springmockito

I have unit test in spring boot written using junit and mockito . I have method that has uses  method which take code block as input and perform required function . Below is sample example of code.

```
class A{
    execute(Codeblock codeblock){
      
    }

   }
 


Class B {
    
   
  C testFunction(){
     return A.execute(()->{
               code to execult ...;
              });
    }
  
  }

class TestB{
    @InjectMock
   B b;
    @Mock
   A a;
 void testFunction(){
    when(A.execult(any())).return(C);
    AssertNotNull(b.testFunction());
    }
}
```

This code is running fine but code coverage is very low because code block is not execute. Is there any way to execute code block and increase coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Testing your class (B) using mocks (A) is correct, the goal is to test any logic in B and verify the interactions with the collaborators (in this case A).

I would then create test for A (mocking Codeblock class), applying the same principle as above.

Finally I would test Codeblock logic independently.